# Effect of wronskian on the solution of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

As far as my understanding goes, the Wronskian $W(t)$ for a second order homogenous differential equation with continuous coefficients can help us govern whether the solutions will be linearly dependent or independent. Suppose we consider $t^2X''-3tX'+3X=0$ which has two solutions $X_1(t)=t^3$ and $X_2(t)=|t^3|$. Clearly, these two solutions are linearly independent over  $R$. But also $W(X_1,X_2)=0$ which implies that either the solutions are identically zero or are linearly dependent. How come a contradiction is arising in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no contradiction since all the theorem about the Wronskian and solutions to ODE are stated and proved for the case when
$$
X''+a(t)X'+b(t)X=0
$$
and $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ are continuous. If you rewrite your equation in this form you'll get the coefficients that are not even defined at $t=0$, hence the theorems that you studied do not work for any potential solutions defined at the point $t=0$. If you restrict your attention to $t>0$ or $t<0$ then, as expected, you will find no contradiction.

Comment: So am I right to conclude that the wronskian only governs about the solutions in the range in which the coefficients are continuous.

Comment: @ShivanshRai It is better to say that the usual theorem about the Wronskian and linear independence of solutions hold only when the coefficients are continuous and the coefficient at the highest derivative is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the equation has the solutions $at^3+bt$, with $a,b\in\mathbb R$. So the Wronskian is nonzero.

You are completely correct with your first sentence.

Comment: $|t^3|$ is obviously also a solution, which is not covered by your formula.

Comment: $|t^3|$ is obviously not a solution, of the equation that matters (or it wouldn't make sense to talk of the Wronskian).

Comment: @Jonas Well, the third person is going to say to you that $\vert t \vert^3$ is a solution, because it is a $C^2$ function and can be nicely plugged into original equation.

Comment: @Evgeny Sure, no problem. :-)